# How this query works in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-injection

I have a table `user` with 2 rows

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id_user` INT(9) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `login` VARCHAR(50),
    `passw` VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
    )  CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    INSERT INTO `user` VALUES 
(NULL, 'Admin', '123'),  
(NULL, 'Nik', '456');
```

then i make a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `login` = '' OR ''='' AND `passw`='' OR ''=''
```

the result :

```
  1  Admin 123
  2  Nik   456
```

So how it works?  What does it mean `''=''`   ?

> I would be grateful if you could advise literature where I can learn about something similar.

Comment: It means "true".  A lot like `1=1`.

Comment: The OR just qualifies a condition... where an empty string = empty string... same as 1=1 or 2=2 similarly applied

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a SQL injection attempt. This:

```
WHERE `login` = '' OR ''='' AND `passw`='' OR ''=''
```

Evaluates as:

```
WHERE `login` = '' 
    OR (''='' AND `passw`='')
    OR ''=''
```

Condition `'' = ''` is always true (the empty string is equal to the empty string), so the `WHERE` clause evaluates as true for every row of the table: the query returns the whole table.